# BASH sed ungreedy match w/back-references

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to work through using back-references to wildcard match sections of some xhtml files but can't seem to get it work with bash sed.

I have gotten it to work with online regex testers using the 'ungreedy' flag but then ran into the problem of not having the 'ungreedy' flag supported in bash sed.

I've attempted a number of proposed workarounds using something like `[+a?]` or `[^/]*` versus what I'm currently using:  `(.*)`

Here are the sample matches from the xhtml files:

```
<td name="MOTD-ENV" style="padding-left:3px"></td>
<td name="MOTD-MSG" style="text-align:right; padding-right:3px"></td>
```

What I'm trying to match is the lines in the file with the tokens for "name="[token-name]" [wildcard]>" so that they can be replace with something like:

```
<td name="MOTD-ENV" style="padding-left:3px">string1</td>
<td name="MOTD-MSG" style="text-align:right; padding-right:3px">string2</td>
```

Here is the sed I'm trying to use to make this:

```
sed -i -re 's/name=\"" + entry.name + "\" (.*)>/name=\"" + entry.name + "\" \\1>" + repl[0]  + "<\/td>/g'
```

The concatenations represent something that's not shown:  that they're being executed from within a Python script in a loop so 'entry.name' evaluates to 'MOTD-ENV' or 'MOTD-MSG' and repl[0] represents that string-data that should go between the  tags.  If the full script is required, I can provide that.

What I've seen as the problem is that the wildcard (.*) is matching too much.  When I've put the filtered match through a regex tester on the web, I can get it to work, as-is, by adding the 'U' flag for 'ungreedy' but according to what I've read, BASH does not support the ungreedy flag.

The strategies offered on other similar issues were either to use perl's regex engine or some offered a different way to match (identified in the 3rd para above).  I could not get any of those other strategies to work.

However, if I added a space character ' ' right after the (.*) and before the '>', it would match.

Is there a way to get a back-reference to work with bash sed with how I'm describing here?

TIA!

Edit - the entire script:

```
import os;
import subprocess;

## The array of paths that have been tokenized to perform the string replacement.
paths = ['file1.xhtml']
        # 'file2.xhtml',
        # 'file3.xhtml',
        # 'file4.xhtml']

with os.scandir('/mnt/secrets-store') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.startswith('MOTD'):
            with open(entry) as f:
                repl = f.readlines()

                for p in paths:
                    if os.path.isfile(p):

                        if entry.name == 'MOTD-TABLE':
                            subprocess.call(["sed -i -re 's/name=\"MOTD-TABLE\" (.*)\"/name=\"MOTD-TABLE\" style=\"" + repl[0]  + "\"/g' " + p], shell=True)
                        elif entry.name == 'MOTD-MSG' and repl[0] == 'NONE':
                            ## Python conditional trap to do nothing if MOTD-MSG secret is-equal-to 'none'
                            print(' ')  ## This condiitonal block cannot be left empty!
                        else:
                            print(entry.name + ' - ' + repl[0])
                            subprocess.call(["sed -pi -re 's/name=\"" + entry.name + "\" (.*)>/name=\"" + entry.name + "\" \\1>" + repl[0]  + "<\/td>/g' " + p
], shell=True)
```

Comment: Are you trying to match the attribute content and nothing more? If so, why not use the fact that XHTML is derived from XML and therefore, you can't have a " character in an attribute, so you could do `name="([^"]*)"` (and maybe `name=("([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')` (`'` is valid in XML) ? And if you use python ... why not do that in Python ?

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to use the name attribute to identify the line that needs to change (because some of the file replacements are performed with different regexes).  However, in this case, the name identifies the line, I want to tokenize whatever the inline 'style' tag is, and then provide a specific value (relative to what name-attribute token is currently being iterated over) between the <td> </td> tags.  Honestly, I'm trying to use sed because I thought I was relatively comfortable with it when I started down this road.  Moving it native to Python might be the way to go.

Comment: I've edited the script to show the Python if anyone if helps show what I'm trying to do.  If I don't get any answers for bash, I'll probably just natively do it in Python.

Comment: Doing it in Python (with one of the several XML libraries included out-of-the-box in the interpreter's standard library -- `ElementTree` being maybe the easiest to use) is absolutely the right approach here. Using `sed` anywhere in the process, by contrast, is dooming someone (maybe your future-self) to needing to fix the hackery when it breaks later, and if the code generating the documents you accept as input isn't set in stone, it _will_ eventually break.

Comment: (Also, using `subprocess.call()` the way you are is setting yourself up for major security problemsif an attacker realizes `entry.name` can be used for a shell escape; data should be kept _out-of-band_ from code -- depending on your copy of `sed`, even permission to run arbitrary sed commands can potentially be enough; see https://gtfobins.github.io/gtfobins/sed/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, entry.name is an MOTD-named file which contents are being written to the xhtml.  This process is entirely OOB from the web page in question.  Its mapping secret values for message-of-the-day coming from Azure keyvaults.  They are stored as secrets but nothing secret in them.  I'm not sure if this minimizes the threat but the consensus seems to be Python-native so I'm going to start working that out.  Thanks for the comments gents.

Comment: BTW, think about using `pass` as the do-nothing command when you can't leave a block empty; that's what it's built for.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy.  This is my first Python script and I'm used to being able to just do nothing in conditional blocks so I appreciate the critique and info on the proper way to do it.

Comment: I'd say like @CharlesDuffy: you are in Python. While I know little of Python (<- Java guy), I know there are facilities in the languages for doing what you seek. They would perform just as well as sed.